Dump firefox profile from RAM
After a failed experiment due to being in a VM, I wanted a separate "clean" browser for recording demonstrations directly on my host. I tried to install a portable version of firefox, which seems to have done something and corrupted my host profile, which I very much did not expect it to do (the entire purpose of getting a portable version of firefox is so I don't mess with my host install and data).

I looked in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles, and tried to delete the profile with the newer modification date, since that presumably came from the botched attempt at using firefox portable, and both folders were empty anyway. I then found out there were lockfiles preventing me from completely deleting the profile, which means that must be my host install of firefox using it. Either way, the profile is now lost on disk, and all that remains is the memory of the current running instance of firefox.
I'm pretty sure if I restart firefox I would lose the profile for good. I don't have much hope, but I figured I might as well ask: is there a way I can dump my browser settings, logins, extensions and their settings, and bookmarks from RAM?
I suppose I can begrudgingly live with painstaking manual backup of everything and / or lost data, but I would really prefer if I didn't have to.

I restarted firefox and the profile is still there. I was looking in the wrong directory - I was looking in the mostly empty local directory %localappdata% rather than the root directory %appdata% where all the important data seems to be, still safe.
Nothing seems to have been lost after all.
